# dev/sda1: clean, 486186/1790544 files, 7077401/7158016 blocks

Tags: boot

[image]

After turning my laptop on, this message appeared and I tried all the ways that are told on the internet but didn’t worked:( My laptop has AMD Vega graphics. Please tell me the solution step by step as simple as possible, thanks in advance!

Comment: Let it finish. Something has triggered the system to demand a check of your file system. Once it's done, so long as everything is good, you won't need to see it again. If this appears often, then it will be important to determine why and take the necessary steps to prevent repeats.

Comment: This is a routine message in the boot process. It tells you that your hard disc (device `/dev/sda1`) has been checked and found to be clean. Unless there's something else going wrong which you didn't tell us about, there's nothing to worry.

Comment: If system boots, it is good message.  Tell us if system just stays there or does not boot/load as it normally does.